# Can't set Ajax rejuest to site

Tags: javascript, jquery

have some problems while sending request to site ( i need to parse some part of a site, thet generates by ajax-request, so i try to send ajax-request). Site redirests me, so such method doesn't works:

```
$.get('http://www.188bet.com/en-gb/Service/LeftIndicator?GetLiveEventDetails&_=1326817486177&IsFirstLoad=true',function (data){alert(data);});
```

This request can't be send, because this site redirects. So someone told me, that i need to send header X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest. So I do so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
});
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.188bet.com/en-gb/Service/LeftIndicator?GetLiveEventDetails&_=1326817486177&IsFirstLoad=true',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

but the result is the same, request is not sended, where is problem?
Site http://www.188bet.com/en-gb/sports, i'm telling about left menu(i need to parse it).

Answer (score 0):

The **Same Origin Policy** prevents cross-domain AJAX requests. If the response is in JSON format, consider JSON-P instead.